# Android 4.1: How to "implement user installable keymaps"?

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard, android-4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard-layout

**Description:**

"User-installable keymaps" are a feature listed for Android 4.1 on http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html.

There it says:

> The platform now supports user-installable keyboard maps, such as for additional international keyboards and special layout types. By default, Android 4.1 includes 27 international keymaps for keyboards, including Dvorak. When users connect a keyboard, they can go to the Settings app and select one or more keymaps that they want to use for that keyboard. When typing, users can switch between keymaps using a shortcut (ctrl-space).
>   You can create an app to publish additional keymaps to the system. The APK would include the keyboard layout resources in it, based on standard Android keymap format. The application can offer additional keyboard layouts to the user by declaring a suitable broadcast receiver for ACTION_QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS in its manifest.

So.. I want to code an app, which adds a new keyboard-layout. So, I have to crate a new BroadcastReveiver and declare it for `ACTION_QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS` in the app's manifest. The app also provides the keymap-file.

**So, my question:** What does the `BroadcastReceiver` have to do, when it receives the `ACTION_QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS` intent?

I've done quite some searching - however, the only sites containing `ACTION_QUERY_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS` I could find where the ones, that copied the description above from developer.android.com.

I would really appreciate any help,

regards,
randall

Answer (score 4):

You need to create one or more suitable [Key Character Map files](http://source.android.com/tech/input/key-character-map-files.html), as raw resource files named e.g. mykeyboard.kcm in your project.

Add the relevant receiver to the manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) with KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS pointing to an XML resource which lists each .kcm file as a keyboard layout. You don't end up writing any actual Java or native code, just the manifest and resource files.

https://github.com/tialaramex/BritishKeyboard

Above link is an example I happened to build earlier today, which (mostly) makes an English (UK) keyboard layout available instead of just the default US keyboard, e.g. pressing SHIFT and 2 gets you double quote instead of the @ symbol. Hopefully this is simple enough to follow if you know a little about Android projects.

The end result is that when you connect a USB or Bluetooth keyboard, the prompt to set a keyboard layout lists any additional keyboard layouts installed by applications, in this case one labelled English (UK).